# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist with many-to-many property

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm creating a job board and when you're creating the job you can select one or more skills to be tied to the job. The job model looks like this:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.date_posted)

    title = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    description = models.TextField()
    payment = models.IntegerField()
    skills = models.ForeignKey(Skill)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    university = models.ManyToManyField(University, blank=True)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    freelancers_applied = models.ManyToManyField(Freelancer, blank=True, related_name="%(class)s_freelancers_applied")
    freelancer_accepted = models.ForeignKey(Freelancer, blank=True, null=True,
                                            related_name="%(class)s_freelancer_accepted")
    completed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_posted = models.DateField(default=django.utils.timezone.now())
    closing_date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

and the skill model looks simply like this:

```
class Skill(models.Model):
    skill = models.TextField(primary_key=True, max_length=128)
```

When the form is posted, I get the skills from `request.POST`, retrieve the skills they represent from the database and I try to add them to the new model, object by object:

```
data = request.POST
j = Job()
skills = Skill.objects.filter(skill__in=data.getlist('skills'))
for skill in skills:
    j.skills.add(skill)
```

When it tries to execute the line `j.skills.add(skill)` it fails with an error

```
RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /jobs/post-job/
Job has no skills.
```

I thought I might have to save the object before I try this but I can't as it violates the not null constraint. The error is also a little vague so my searches aren't going well. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

I think the issue is related to the concept.

It seems that a `Job` can have several `Skill`s related. Can a `Skill` be related to several `Jobs`? If yes, then you have to declare it as a `ManyToManyField` instead of a `ForeignKey`. Otherwise, `Job` has to be a `ForeignKey` in `Skill` and not the other way around.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'Job' object has no attribute 'skills_set'` unfortunately

Comment: `ValueError: Cannot assign "[<Skill: Web Development>, <Skill: Graphic Design>, <Skill: Software Development>]": "Job.skills" must be a "Skill" instance.`

Comment: @Nanor I completely changed the answer, hope it helps now.